# Can a logarithm be written as a power using only rational numbers?

Tags: logarithms, exponentiation, irrational-numbers, rational-numbers

I was thinking about the fact that we can write certain irrational numbers as the result of an exponentiation of rational numbers, for example $\sqrt2=2^{0.5}$. My question is, can a irrational logarithm with rational operands be written as a power with a rational base and a rational exponent?

For example, let's take $y=\log_23$, is the following statement true?

$$\exists p, q\in\mathbb Q:p^q=y$$

If so, could you give a pair of values that makes this statement true?

Comment: This would mean that $y$ is algebraic. I strongly doubt this is true for general logarithms, $\log_ab$ with $a,b$ rational.

Comment: Specifically, if $y=p^q,$ let $d$ be a non-zero integer such that $qd$ is an integer. Then $y^d=p^{qd}$ is rational.

Comment: This is not possible for $\log_a(b)$ if $a$ and $b$ are integers that are not both powers of the same number since that number will be transcendental whereas $p^q$ is an algebraic number.

Comment: In the case of the natural logarithm the answer is essentially no. This is because the exceptional set of $\exp$ is $\{0\}$. This means the only number which has an algebraic logarithm is $1$ (This is a more general statement than the one in your question). Other logarithms are directly related to the natural logarithm so there is likely a generalization, but it will potentially not be as simple.